# How to get icon for hidden file (like Explorer) for ListView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listview

I use`SHGetFileInfo('', 0, aFileInfo, SizeOf(TSHFileInfo), SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX)` to extract an icon list in `TImageList` and then associate index with `TListView`. Which flag I must use to get hidden style like Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the system does not offer such functionality. You need to create faded icons yourself, based on the original icon. You can use a function along these lines to do that:

```
function CreateFadedIcon(Icon: HICON): HICON;

type
  TRGBA = record
    B,G,R,A: Byte
  end;

  procedure InitialiseBitmapInfoHeader(Width, Height: Integer; var bih: BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  begin
    bih.biSize := SizeOf(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bih.biWidth := Width;
    bih.biHeight := 2*Height;//height of xor bitmap plus height of and bitmap
    bih.biPlanes := 1;
    bih.biBitCount := 32;
    bih.biCompression := BI_RGB;
  end;

  procedure CreateXORbitmap(const sbih, dbih: BITMAPINFOHEADER; sptr, dptr: PDWORD);
  var
    i, j: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to sbih.biHeight-1 do begin
      for j := 0 to sbih.biWidth-1 do begin
        dptr^ := sptr^;
        TRGBA(dptr^).A := TRGBA(dptr^).A div 3;
        inc(dptr);//relies on the fact that no padding is needed for RGBA scanlines
        inc(sptr);//likewise
      end;
    end;
  end;

var
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  sBits, xorBits: PDWORD;
  xorScanSize, andScanSize: Integer;
  xorBitsSize, andBitsSize: Integer;
  sbih: BITMAPINFOHEADER;
  dbih: ^BITMAPINFOHEADER;
  resbitsSize: DWORD;
  resbits: Pointer;

begin
  Result := 0;
  Try
    if not GetIconInfo(Icon, IconInfo) then begin
      exit;
    end;
    Try
      GetDIBheaderAndBits(IconInfo.hbmColor, sbih, Pointer(sBits));
      if Assigned(sBits) then begin
        Try
          if (sbih.biPlanes<>1) or (sbih.biBitCount<>32) then begin
            exit;
          end;

          xorScanSize := BytesPerScanline(sbih.biWidth, 32, 32);
          Assert(xorScanSize=SizeOf(DWORD)*sbih.biWidth);
          andScanSize := BytesPerScanline(sbih.biWidth, 1, 32);
          xorBitsSize := sbih.biHeight*xorScanSize;
          andBitsSize := sbih.biHeight*andScanSize;
          resbitsSize := SizeOf(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + xorBitsSize + andBitsSize;
          resbits := AllocMem(resbitsSize);//AllocMem zeroises the memory
          Try
            dbih := resbits;
            InitialiseBitmapInfoHeader(sbih.biWidth, sbih.biHeight, dbih^);

            xorBits := resbits;
            inc(PByte(xorBits), SizeOf(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
            CreateXORbitmap(sbih, dbih^, sBits, xorBits);

            //don't need to fill in the mask bitmap when using RGBA
            Result := CreateIconFromResourceEx(resbits, resbitsSize, True, $00030000, sbih.biWidth, sbih.biHeight, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
          Finally
            FreeMem(resbits);
          End;
        Finally
          FreeMem(sBits);
        End;
      end;
    Finally
      if IconInfo.hbmMask<>0 then begin
        DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmMask);
      end;
      if IconInfo.hbmColor<>0 then begin
        DeleteObject(IconInfo.hbmColor);
      end;
    End;
  Finally
    DestroyIcon(Icon);
  End;
end;
```